# Install/Load "klaR" Package error: no package called ‘labelled’

Tags: r, installation, package, regression

I'm trying to install klaR and its library using the code below:

```
install.packages("klaR")
library(klaR)
```

I need it to do different types of stepwise regressions on my data later on.  However, when I run the code above it gives me the following error

> library(klaR) package �klaR� was built under R version 3.6.3Error:
> package or namespace load failed for ‘klaR’ in loadNamespace(j <-
> i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is
> no package called ‘labelled’

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have the `labelled` package installed?

Comment: I installed 'labelled' and tried to run my code ... it still give me : Error: package klaR is required

Comment: So installing `klaR` returns an error about not having `labelled`, while installing `labelled` returns an error about not having `klaR`? R usually handles package installation pretty well. Have you changed any defaults? The installation works fine for me. Maybe restart R?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `rlang` package.
`install.packages("rlang")`,
then install package `labelled`,
then try loading `klaR`